# SSRS adding sub-data to report

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, reporting-services

In SSRS, I have a report that is pulling in information for a building in one row.

I have dates and Rent amounts for the building that I want to be shown as "future information" under the row. What this means is, If my building row is showing $1500 of rent for this "As of" Date, I want the report to show, based on my database, 2017,2018,2019,2020 with the respective $$ increases for those years. Example:

```
 |unit   | rent  | total| FutureDate   | Rent|

 |ABC    |$1500  |$1500 |
 |       |       |      | 2017         |1600 |
 |       |       |      | 2018         |1650 |
 |       |       |      | 2019         |1700 |
 |       |       |      | 2020         |1750 |
```

I am a bit new to SSRS, my current report is only showing 2017 and 1600: 1 row. How could I make it show all future dates, if it is grouping by the Unit?
Currently my only expressions are =Fields!FutureDate.Value and =Fields!Rent.Value for that space. Is this a grouping issue or a expression issue?

Comment: Are the increased rent values fields in your dataset? or are they calculated based on present rent values? Explain.

Comment: Yes, they are in my dataset under Rent. The other driving factor is the date. The first row is always the current year. I am confused on how to get the following 4 proceeding years with corresponding rent next to it as shown in the example above.

Answer (score 0):

I've recreated your scenario with the following sample dataset. Assuming you have a similar dataset.

[image]

You have to add a tablix with the following data arrangement:

[image]

It will preview the below table:

[image]

Let me know if my answer helps you.